# Mac keychain github keys

Tags: mac, git, passwords, github, keychain

I am new mac user and I find keychain very useful, but also some issues appeared. I have private and business github accounts, so I like to switch between them and configure github profile for each project local. However, my mac's keychain each time saves new password and applies it for each project, folder etc. So, when I am switching between projects I must always delete github.com record from keychain and type credentials again. Could you tell me how can I set my git's passwords being ignored by keychain? Any other solutions?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you're using a GUI tool to access github, if Keychain is involved.  If you're comfortable using git on the command-line, you could easily create a couple aliases to switch between users.

Comment: @MMB I am using console

Comment: Odd.  I've never seen Keychain when using git from the command-line.  I found a number of useful, but lengthy posts by Googling "github multiple accounts" and "github work personal" so give that a try.

Comment: Keychain can also be invoked even using command line git.